# Override Activity object's onActivityResult from another class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I passed an activity object to some class:

```
// SomeClass.java constructor
public SomeClass(Activity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
}
```

I need to use the startActivityForResult of the activity object:

```
private void goToAnotherActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.mActivity, AnotherActivity.class);
    this.mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_KEY);
}
```

Is it possible to override the this.mActivity's onActivityResult from SomeClass.java?

Comment: what do you actually want with this?

Comment: I am using the twitter4j library. It will go to TwitterOAuthActivity.java for the login process. As I will call the library in different activities, I'm looking for a more generic way of doing that instead of copy and paste loads of code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly call `onActivityResult()`. Just override it in the `Activity` passed to SomeClass and it will be executed when `AnotherActivity` is finished. If you need to, you can create a `BaseActivity` which overrides `onActivityResult()` and have the activities you intend to pass on to SomeClass extend `BaseActivity`.

Another approach would be to use the Java reflection/instrumentation API to override the method in `mActivity` on-the-fly, in case it is really necessary.

Comment: SomeClass.java did't extend Activity and it is an object, so it can't override onActivityResult().

Comment: Sorry, I meant override it in the Activity passed to SomeClass. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, which means I have to create another intermediate Activity class, and make all the activities extend it but cannot do in in SomeClass.java right?

Comment: Right, unless you use the reflection/instrumentation API on mActivity from inside SomeClass as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the BaseActivity is the easiest way to do that.